# Вызов popen() процессом, обладающим правами администратора

Tags: linux, c

Необходимо прочитать вывод дочернего терминала, но `popen()` нельзя запускать с административными правами. Какие здесь возможны варианты?

Comment: Где в мануале написано, что нельзя? (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

Comment: архитектор запретил наверное) а варианты fork+execv)

Comment: @eri так это ж те же ооциты, только в профиль

Comment: но пока не запрещенные)

Comment: "запуск c административными правами" и сами "правами администратора" бывают только на windows

Comment: Да, не корректно выразился